# Restrict a [magento] coupon code to a specific list of customers?

Tags: magento

Any ideas on how to restrict the coupon code to be used by a specific list of customers?

Background: My company is doing a promo, and we *already* emailed a discount code out to a list of 2000+ highly valuable customers.  We don't want ALL of our customers to be able to use the code, just the ones in our list.  And the problem is that the coupon code has already been posted on some popular forums, and other places, so unless we do something to prevent it, we'll get a bunch of orders from folks that weren't intended to get the code.

I am trying to do some emergency damage control - I figure I am gonna have to make a code modification somewhere, but I am still looking around, can't figure out the best place.  I have a list of customers in a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create an observer observing `salesrule_validator_process` (this event is triggered when a shopping cart rule is applied) which would have to check 2 things:

- the rule applied is the rule you wanna restrict to your customers list:

  ```
  $ruleId = $observer->getEvent()->getRule()->getRuleId();
  ```
- if the first condition is met, then check that the customer is logged in and that is email is one of the emails in your list:

  ```
  if ($observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getCustomer()->getEmail()) {
      $customerEmail = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getCustomer()->getEmail();
      if ($customerEmail IS ON YOUR LIST) {
          return $this;
      } else {
          $event = $observer->getEvent();
          $result = $event->getResult();
          $result->setBaseDiscountAmount(0)->setDiscountAmount(0);
  } else {
      $event = $observer->getEvent();
      $result = $event->getResult();
      $result->setBaseDiscountAmount(0)->setDiscountAmount(0);
  }
  ```

you should refactor this code to queep it DRY, and also I haven't make an actual if condition, but you get the picture.
also you'll have to change the message "coupon has been succesfully applied".
tell me if you need more details.

Comment: I haven't yet had a chance to fully code/test this (other priorities came up), but this definitely looks solid. Thanks bud.

Comment: sorry for a little of topic, @Osdave: how can you can find which event is the one we're looking for for particular action in Magento

Comment: @Vdt I usually use the combination of logging all events by editing Mage::dispatchEvent() method and adding this line `Mage::log($name, null, 'events.txt', TRUE);` and putting breakpoints in xdebug. Like that I can see which events are triggered around the functionnality I am looking to work with. HTH

Comment: @OSdave thanks for your tips, it's really useful for new mag dev like me :)

Comment: @Vdt np, glad I can help. welcome in the fabulous world of Magento programing :)

Answer (score 1):

Sdek u can create the oberver like Osdave explained. Or if u have  a list of customers who have received the Promo code & ur not willing to let them use that promo.
u can do as follows

1. Prepare the list (emails)
2. Create a Customer Group NO-promo-Customer
3. prepare a script may be an SQL query that updates the Customer Group of users in ur list to No-promo-customer
4. Go to that promo Rule that u have created. edit it. & Under section **Customer Groups** choose No-promo-Customer

This should fulfill what ur trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [customer discounts](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-discount-rules.html)

Comment: Hmm, that looks nice.  Well I wasn't completely up front in my original question... the coupon code has already been sent out! and so I am trying to do some emergency damage control :)  So I don't think that extension would work for me in this case, but we may be interested in something like that going forward.  Thanks.